# Why is the spanning tree algorithm used for bridge-routing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees

In a network of LANs connected by bridges, packets are sent from one LAN to another through intermediate bridges. Since more than one path may exist between two LANs, packets may have to be routed through multiple bridges. Why is the spanning tree algorithm used for bridge-routing?

1. For shortest path routing between LANs
2. For avoiding loops in the routing paths
3. For fault tolerance
4. For minimizing collisions

---

According to wiki :

"The [Spanning Tree Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) (STP) is a network protocol that ensures a loop-free topology for Ethernet networks."

> Can you explain little bit please, why option $(1)$ is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case where there is at most one direct connection between any two segments of the network, suppose the network topology is *not* already  tree, and that a spanning tree has been selected. There will be some link that is *not* in the spanning tree ... and the shortest path between the two ends of that link would certainly be to *use that link* (for a distance of 1 hop) rather than route along the spanning tree (for a distance of at least 2 hops, maybe more).

Comment: So, for shortest path we should use SSSP(single source shortest path) algorithm. rt sir ?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: Well, sort of. SSSP is the name of the _problem_ you would solve at each node to find a shortest path, but there are various different ways to solve it. Some routing protocols do do this, at the cost of being more complex to configure, but STP is not one of them.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: And don't "sir" me -- I'm neither a customer in your shop nor your military superior. As a random internet user volunteering my time, I expect at least to be treated with the minimum of respect that you'll try to pretend to consider me an equal.

Comment: In India, we call "sir" for any respectable person, but someone told me, in other countries "sir" prefix is used for customer in any hotel.
Anyway, I will be remember this. Thanks for nice explanation.